# is there any protocol other than SIP for VOIP

Tags: android, protocols, sip, voip

I am new to android.I want to build a VOIP app.I made an app using SIP but could not test the application as my cell phone does not support SIP.Please suggest me any protocol and Library so that i can design a good and generic app for all version of android.
Advance thanks for all.

Comment: You can implement SIP protocol on your own, if a particular version of Android doesnt have it

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not SIP itself, it is the built-in API that is not supported by all handsets.

You can use [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org/), a widely used SIP stack that should supports a wider variety of Android hansets.